# How can we convert com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate to YYYY/MM/DD format?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, lombok, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I want to convert the `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate` object returned by the API to `yyyy-MM-dd` format. How can I do that?

I tried below code but it is not working for `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate`-

```
 @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") 
 String date;
```

Comment: paste your code snippet please

Comment: It won't work like this buddy, you'll have to paste code sniped in your question and format it properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can do it using annotation but below is one way of explicitly converting  `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate` to `yyyy-MM-dd` format -

```
java.util.Date dateObj = new java.util.Date(localDate.getMillisSinceEpoch());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdf.format(dateObj);
```